# Custom Attributes to Lucene Tokens

Tags: java, solr, lucene

I am new to Lucene. I am trying to have custom attributes to tokens. I was able to get the attributes assigned to tokens. However I realise that we need to roughly have 3 files (Interface Class extending Attribute , Class extending AttributeImpl and a Class extending TokenFilter) for each of my Attribute?

I might have about 50 attributes that I need to assign. Do I have to have 3 files per Attribute? that is about 150 files.

Or is there some way I can reduce that. I am sure there is something that I am not able to find.

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: 50 attributes sounds like a lot. Can you tell us more about your use-case, maybe there is a better way to solve your problem?

Comment: Well, Not that each token will have all the 50 attributes. But there will be around 50 attributes in total. Eg: "The xyz(feature) of abc( product) has problems in installation"
I will have the tokens split by whitespace and then would like to tag "xyz" with the following attributes : Feature, Noun etc.
"problems" could have the following attributes: Noun Plural, Negative word etc.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need as many attributes as you have token "types". All you need to have is a single attribute which has a member that tells what your token is. You could reuse or get some inspiration from Lucene's TypeAttribute.

Comment: Any link where I can get an example of all the Lucene built-in Attributes(Like the TypeAttribute, Payload, PositionIncrement)?

Comment: http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/lucene/dev/trunk/lucene/core/src/java/org/apache/lucene/analysis/tokenattributes/

Comment: Thanks for the link. However there is no explanation with the usage right? More precisely.

Comment: Does the TokenStream javadoc http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_3_0/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/TokenStream.html help?